# Add data dynamicly with highcharts using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, highcharts

so i'm trying to make a chart, using highcharts, that could handle a stream of information, for now i'm trying with random values and it doesn't work as intended as i get the error : `"TypeError: this.options is undefined"`
And the error refers to the highcharts.js file and not the current file,
So is it a problem with my highcharts installation or am i doing something wrong here?

Here is the full code if anyone has any clue and thanks !
`

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { withHighcharts, HighchartsStockChart, Chart} from 'react-jsx-highstock';
  import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';

class Charts extends React.Component{
ReactHighcharts = require('react-highcharts');

componentDidMount(props) {
Highcharts.chart('container', {
 chart: {
    events: {
        load: function () {
           var series = this.series[0];
           var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                  y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
           setInterval(function () {
             console.log("Y : " ,y);
                 series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);

             }, 1000);
        }
    }
},

 title: {
   text: 'BPM Chart'
 },

 scrollbar: {
   enabled: false
 },

 rangeSelector: {
   selected: 1
 },

 exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
    name: 'Random data',
    data: (function () {
        // generate an array of random data
        var data = [],
            time = (new Date()).getTime(),
            i;

        for (i = -9; i <= 0; i += 1) {
            data.push([
                time + i * 1000,
                Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
            ]);
        }
        return data;
    }())
}]

});
}
render() {
return (
 <div>
   <div id="container" onLoad="componentDidMount()">loading </div>
 </div>
  )
  }
  }
  export default Charts;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `ReactHighcharts = require('react-highcharts');` since you have a mixture of several `highchart` related libraries.  A little bit of cleaning and now it works. However, I would stick with [react-highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-highcharts) `npm` instead.

Here is a working example:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';

class Charts extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(props) {
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                events: {
                    load: function () {
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                        setInterval(function () {
                            console.log("Y : " ,y);
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);

                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },

            title: {
                text: 'BPM Chart'
            },

            scrollbar: {
                enabled: false
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Random data',
                data: (function () {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -9; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                        data.push([
                            time + i * 1000,
                            Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                        ]);
                    }
                    return data;
                }())
            }]

        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="container">loading </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <Charts></Charts>
    , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here is another example using `react-highcharts npm`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactHighcharts from 'react-highcharts'

var conf =  {
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function () {
                var series = this.series[0];
                var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                    y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                setInterval(function () {
                    console.log("Y : " ,y);
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);

                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'BPM Chart'
    },

    scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        data: (function () {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -9; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push([
                    time + i * 1000,
                    Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                ]);
            }
            return data;
        }())
    }]

};


ReactDOM.render(
    <ReactHighcharts config = {conf}></ReactHighcharts>
    ,document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i already tried it, but i finally solved the problem, it was a conflict of previous installations of highcharts, did some cleaning and reinstalling it with npm and everything works fine now :D